# Search on via field in GMail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

Is there a way to search the *via* part of a from address in GMail?

I'm trying to set up a filter which finds the following message that comes from:

`no-reply@another-company.com via my-company-domain.com`

When I search for `from:my-company-domain` the message isn't found. Is there a way to find it based on the value show as the `via` address?